# Creating a workbook with apache poi 4.1.2 throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xls

When I try to create a workbook from an already existing xls received as an InputStream using apache poi 4.1.2:

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(input);
Workbook workbook = null;

try {
   workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
...
}
```

I received the following exception: "Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Unable to read 512 bytes from 328192 in stream of length 328192"
If I open the xls file and just save it before uploaded it again, it works fine.

Comment: Broken upload code that doesn't work reliably and misses bytes at the end?

Comment: Is the data in the xls file sensitive?  I'd be willing to troubleshoot this but I would need to see the file

Comment: @Kayaman, I don't think the upload code is broken. It worked for thousands of files.

Comment: So you're absolutely sure that you get all the bytes at the server? Because the error message is indicating that it's missing bytes. I trust the error message more than I trust you. Was the size of that file `328192` bytes, or more than that? If it was more, then you didn't read all the bytes.

Comment: @Chris Maggiulli, that's what I think too. Unfortunately, I can't share with you the file. This file does not have the protected view enable, although it is enabled in Trust Center.

Comment: @Kayaman, the length of the byte [] is 331264 same as the xls file size from the properties.

Comment: The exception says that the size is `328192`, not `331264`.

Comment: Yes, I see that, the exception is from apache poi library. I can't figure if this is a bug or the xls file is corrupt or something.